# Segmentation fault while passing string array

Tags: c++

I went through similar question on stackoverflow but it did not solve my issue

I am trying to send string array as below

```
void manipulateString( char *);
int hashTable (int &, char * );
const int HTsize = 10;
int main()
{
    const int size = 100;
    char inputString[size];

    cout << " Enter first names ( separate by a space ) \n ";
    cin.getline(inputString,size);

    manipulateString(inputString);

    return 0;
}

    void manipulateString (char *input)
{

    int firstNamelen;
    int hIndex=0,newIndex=0;
    int totalName = 0;

    char *firstname;
    firstname = strtok(input, " ");  // separate firstname

    while (firstname != NULL)
    {   

    firstNamelen = strlen(firstname);
    hIndex = hashfunction(firstname,firstNamelen);

    newIndex=hashTable(hIndex, firstname);
    cout << "\n\n ( " << firstname << " ) is stored at index [" << hIndex  << "] of hash table " << endl;

    firstname = strtok(NULL, " " ); // next first name

    }
}
```

When it reaches to `void manipulateString (char *input)` it gives segmentation fault. what is the issue?

Comment: What is `manipulateString()` and what does it do? I'm no C++ expert, does the `size` argument to `getline` take the null-terminator in account?

Comment: I removed the 'c' tag, this is C++.

Comment: The issue is likely in the code of `manipulateString` itself, and not only in its call.

Comment: if you can use C++, why not use `std::string`? You obviously want string operations

Comment: (1) `char* input`is a single string, not a string array. (2) Are you sure the line is less than 100 characters long? (3) why are you not just using `std::string` and `std::getline(std::istream &, std::string &)` ?

Comment: the program you have shown runs fine without segfault. while your effort to put together a short example which illustrates your problem is nice, the problem probably lies in the implementation of the (in the example empty) manipulateString function... the only problem in the code above is if you enter more than 100 characters...

Comment: I updated the code with function contains. I tried with debugger it gives Segf just after function call!

Comment: Well, now we have another function that isn't known: `hashTable`

Comment: It's SSCCE time again... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: @Medinoc: Ok, but what is the benefit os (3) ?

Comment: (3) allows to read lines without worrying about a maximum length.

Answer (score 2):

*Given that `hashfunction` and `hashTable` are not leading to a segmentation fault...*

You can only read `size-1` characters.
Check `cin.fail()` to see whether `cin.getline` was successfull. If not the string might not be `NULL` terminated. If the string is not `NULL` terminated, `strlen` or `strtok` might lead to a segmentation fault.